# Group objects with matching properties into Lists

Tags: c#, list, object, nested-lists, linq-group

I have a List of objects in C#.  All the objects contain properties code1 and code2 (among other properties).

Example:

```
List -> object = id, name, code1, code2, hours, amount.
```

There are 31 possible code1 values.
There are 10 possible code2 values.

I need to group together all objects having the same code1 and code2 values (the unique combination) into their own Lists which would be saved within a parent list (so that each individual list could be iterated over later.)

Comment: Have you tried filtering your list with LINQ ?
It makes List filtering easy with Sql Query syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.code1, x.code2 });

// Example of iterating...
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}:", group.Key.code1, group.Key.code2);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0} ({1})", item.id, item.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it work same as if I cast it to new object => list.GroupedBy(x=>new TempObject{x.code1,x.code2});

Answer (score 4):

Enumerable extensions is your friend (are* your friends? :)

```
var groups = lists.GroupBy(item => new { item.code1, item.code2 });
```

And....the legendary Skeet hit post before I did, the SHAME!

Time to one up Skeet (ha, right). You could also group your common items in a dictionary.

```
var mapping = list
  .GroupBy(item => new { item.code1, item.code2 })
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Now mapping is a `Dictionary<anon{code1, code2}, List<YourObject>>`. Of course you could leave off the ToList for the value, and the value type of the dictionary would be an IGrouping, which is an IEnumerable.

You could also use ToLookup

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(item => new { item.code1, item.code2 });
```

The result is an ILookup which has a key of the key Type given, and is an IEnumerable of the list type used. It's not a dictionary, but can be used similarly.

Comment: It would be simpler to use `list.ToLookup(x => new { item.code1, item.code2 })` :)